# Unit Law in Category Definition

Tags: category-theory

In the definition of a category, why is the unit law a necessary part of the definition of a category? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: There are things called [semicategories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semicategory).

Comment: Because the structure so defined is one we're interested in studying. I'm not entirely sure what would answer this question. For a comparison, what sort of answer would you accept if your question was "Why does the definition of a monoid require an identity element?" or "Why does the definition of  ring require a multiplicative identity and an additive identity?"

Answer (score 3):

Because, at a basic level, the point of a category is to make sense of isomorphic/equivalent objects.  For that, you need to be able to compare maps to the identity.

Comment: How can comparing maps to identity allow you to make sense of isomorphic/equivalent objects? Could you give an example?

Comment: Because the definition of isomorphism is phrased in terms of compositions and identity maps, so a category should have both.